# SIGABRT on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, sigabrt

I have this code, that I copied out of the default MasterDetail App, yet when I run the program, it stalls on the line with the declaration of the cell.  And I have no clue why.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row].title as String
    cell.textLabel.text = object
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't register cell to use on table view

   I hope you forgot to do this.

   ```
   self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   ```
2. If you didn't register the cell for tableview, then it may return nil to cell.

Apple Says

```
let == Constant

var == variable values at any time
```

So using ? will consider as optional

you should have like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    //OR

    //var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell

    //Your stuff

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [This tutorial from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1), you may want to check the Table View on the story board.

Look for the attribute inspector for the Table View and verify that the "content" field is set to "Dynamic Prototypes". Updating this fixed it for me.

Also, while you have the hood open, verify that there is a single table cell in the table view, and make sure that it's "Identifier" field is set to the value you had in the `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method call (in your case "cell")